# Change the link underline color in Keynote

Tags: keynote

How do I change the color in keynote of the link that underlines text? I have a presentation template where the links are underlined in teal. This is annoying. I want them underlined in black. I can change the color of the text, but not of the underline.

Answer (score 4):

Select the text, press CMD-T to open the Fonts panel (from the Format > Font menu), then change the underline color via the underline popup's Colour menu item.

Please see image below.

[image: Fonts panel underline color]